# Navbar issue in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have made my navbar items to open on hover on big screens

As soon as i resize the navbar to small screen and refresh the page once again the navbar opens on hover on small screen devices also how to prevent that I want to disable that on hover thing for small screen devices ??

Any solution please do provide

Comment: just try to use media query for those things. put the width size from which you don't want to use hove effect to the navbar for that `ul.nav li:hover{display:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to solve the issue

```
 @media (min-width: 320px) 
 {
   ul.nav li:hover
   {
     display: block;
    }
 }
```

**Note:** You can use screen size according to demand.

Comment: You should change these  ul.nav li according to your class also, you can try display: none;